# JOliver's EventStore: Cannot read events when using ServiceStack serializer

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, neventstore

EventMessage.Body isn't deserialized back into the original object when using ServiceStack. Instead EventMessage.Body is a JSON string.

To reproduce:

1. Open the EventStore project and navigate to the EventStore.Example project
2. Replace the EventStore.Serialization.Json references with project references to EventStore.Serialization.ServiceStack
3. Turn off assembly signing on EventStore.Example project
4. Change MainProgram.WireupEventStore to .UsingServiceStackJsonSerialization()
5. Add the following code near the end of MainProgram.Main():

-

```
var stream = store.OpenStream(StreamId, 0, int.MaxValue);
var myFirstEvent = (SomeDomainEvent) (stream.CommittedEvents.First().Body);
Console.Out.WriteLine("MyFirstEvent.Value=" + myFirstEvent.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a string and you're expecting SomeDomainEvent you could use ServiceStack's **FromJson** Extension method, i.e:

```
var myFirstEvent = stream.CommittedEvents.First().Body.FromJson<SomeDomainEvent>();
Console.Out.WriteLine("MyFirstEvent.Value=" + myFirstEvent.Value);
```

Comment: With this solution we end up deserializing the event twice mostly negating any performance benefits of switching to ServiceStack from Newton. Utimately I think this is a bug with the EventStore/ServiceStack plugin or we are using it incorrectly. I've upvoted your answer but left the question unanswered.